# Self referencing loop detected for property in Web Application

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, vs-web-application-project

I am trying to port a mobile service app to a web application.  To do so I created a new web application and copied the relevant code from the working mobile service to the new web application that I created (using the mobile app template.
I have the following code in my Startup method in the new application:

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;


        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();
   }
}
```

The config.Formatters were copied from the original application which returns the entity and its children to the json output of the api controller.

In the new application I had to add the [MobileAppController] to my api controllers.  I get the following error from the controller in the web application app:  Self referencing loop detected for property Teams 
(The model has Teams --> Players and players has a teamid)

Based on this detailed question:
[Self referencing loop detected - Getting back data from WebApi to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313632/self-referencing-loop-detected-getting-back-data-from-webapi-to-the-browser)

The above code should work as it does in my mobile service app.  The web service app appears to ignore the config.Formatters value as I have tried every value in the above question but I still get the same error.
If I place the [JSON Ignore] attribute before the Child list, then I do not get the error, but also do not get the children back in the json.  How can I get this web application to accept the formatting values?

Comment: Is this a dup of [Azure Mobile App customizing json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941834/azure-mobile-app-customizing-json-serialization) ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could add attributes to your classes directly, for instance [JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemIsReference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemIsReference.htm) to force `PreserveReferencesHandling` for collection items.

Comment: Thank you  for your useful comments.  Thank you @dbc for pointing me to this question.  I spent 3 days looking and didn't find it.  So apparently I was correct that the mobile app is ignoring the json formatters.  You let me to this post [json net error].  Adding the attribute  [JsonObject(IsReference = true)] before the DTOs solved the problem with minimum code.   [json net error]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type/

Comment: @HaimKatz This should be an answer and not a comment... this was wrecking my head.

Answer (score 0):

hank you for your useful comments. Thank you @dbc for pointing me to this question. I spent 3 days looking and didn't find it. So apparently I was correct that the mobile app is ignoring the json formatters. You let me to this post [json net error]. Adding the attribute [JsonObject(IsReference = true)] before the DTOs solved the problem with minimum code. [json net error]:stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/… – Haim Katz Jul 24 at 13:41

Comment: as per inkers request